# php replace multiple possible occurrences of <br> before <tag>

Tags: php, regex

Example; a piece of HTML code contains the tag `<tag />`. Before or after this tag, there can be an unknown number of `<br>` tags before, or after the `<tag />` tag. How do I remove these without removing all other `<br>` tags with a PHP function like preg_replace?

To clarify a bit more, let's assume this is a piece of HTML that needs to be filtered:

`Text.<br><br><tag />More text.<br>And there is another line of text.<br><br><br><tag />And even more text.`

The result should be:

`Text.<tag />More text.<br>And there is another line of text.<tag />And even more text.`

So, all `<br>` occurrences before or after (can be multiple) the `<tag >` need to be removed.

Makes sense?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is this an HTML file you're reading in or are you wanting to process the running HTML in real time with javascript?

Comment: Look at the title, I need to do this in PHP, possibly with a regex. ;)

Comment: Post some code so we can see what you're doing. Show us what you've tried.

Comment: Havn't tried anything yet, because I have no clue on how to do this, hence the question. But in short, I need to be able to replace these:

`Text.<br><br><tag />More text.` and 
`Text.<br><tag />More text.` and 
`Text.<br><br><br><tag />More text.`

 with 

`Text.<tag />More text.`

Comment: What's with the down-votes by the way? Jees...

Comment: If you take the stackoverflow tour, you'll see the very first item explains that this isn't a discussion forum. It's meant for posting what you're trying to do, what you've tried, and where you're stuck. It's not a big deal. Go try something and update this question with the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use positive lookarounds. Use the below regex to match all the `br` tags which exists before and after to `<tag />` tag. Just replace the matched tags with an empty string to get your desired output.

```
(?:<br>)+(?=<tag \/>)|(?<=<tag \/>)(?:<br>)+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lS8aQ1/1)

```
$re = "/(?:<br>)+(?=<tag \\/>)|(?<=<tag \\/>)(?:<br>)+/m";
$str = "Text.<br><br><tag />More text.<br>And there is another line of text.<br><br><br><tag />And even more text.";
$subst = "";
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thank you soo much @Avinash Raj, that cracked it! Thumbs up.